# Bash completion throwing syntax error

Tags: linux, bash, shell

#### THE PROBLEM:

Say I'm trying to change to a directory called 'build' which is in the directory I'm currently in. I start:

```
cd b
```

Then I hit tab once (knowing that no other directories in the current one begins with the letter `b`). I expect to see the following, ready for me to hit return or change or augment as needed.

```
cd build
```

However, on my netbook which runs Linux Peppermint 3, I find that this appears when I press the tab button:

```
cd bbash: command substitution: line 74: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
bash: command substitution: line 74: `            done'
```

#### THINGS I'VE TRIED:

- I've tried reinstalling the "bash-completion" package but this had no apparent effect.
- I've looked at the file `/etc/bash_completion` and specifically at line 74 but I can see nothing obvious there that would need correcting (`complete -f -X '*.Z' compress znew`). Perhaps I am looking in the wrong file.
- I find completion for commands like `git`, `gedit`, and `node` work okay. But trying to auto-complete a filename for `kate` also doesn't work.
- When I ran `bash -x` for debugging, a lot of code was printed in the terminal and this was at the end (note the comment):

  ```
  + toks=(${toks[@]-} $(
      compgen -d -- "$quoted" | {
          while read -r tmp; do
              # TODO: I have removed a "[ -n $tmp ] &&" before 'printf ..',
              #       and everything works again. If this bug suddenly
              #       appears again (i.e. "cd /b<TAB>" becomes "cd /"),
              #       remember to check for other similar conditionals (here
              #       and _filedir_xspec()). --David
              printf '%s\n' $tmp
          done
      }
  ))
  bash: command substitution: line 74: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
  bash: command substitution: line 74: `            done'
  ```

  I tried adding the conditional mentioned back in but this had no effect.
- I've tried temporarily removing `etc/bash_completion.d` but this had no effect.
- I've tried `complete -p` to see a list of completions but I don't really know what I'm looking for.

#### A FINAL PLEA

I'm willing to get my hands dirty with the shell scripts if that's what takes; I can learn a bit more about this in the process. I really would it fixed though. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Bash completion is modular; different packages provide their own completion extensions. Another package probably contains the bug. Try `mv /etc/bash_completion.d{,.old}` and see if that fixes it. If so, do `mv /etc/bash_completion.d{.old,}` to move it back again, and then move individual files out of the `/etc/bash_completion.d` directory one by one to identify the file that is causing the problem. (The directory might be called something slightly different on Peppermint.)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but no joy. There is a directory called `/etc/bash_completion.d` in my instance of Peppermint and I was able to rename/move as you suggested but the problem remains as described.

Comment: Maybe you have to restart bash before it will notice that change? Try opening a new terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the further tip. Still no luck, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Can't officially comment yet, so I'll offer a partial answer pointing into another direction. Could you check your key bindings?

```
$ bind -p | grep -i tab
```

I have come across environments in the past where people had decided to bind the tab key with a functionality. The other option is to fork off a bash shell using the "-x" parameter, like so:

```
$ bash -x
```

Repeat your test. Does it happen as well if you use `echo` instead of `cd`?

```
$ echo b <tab>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. To answer your last question first, `echo` did not produce the same effect. The first command you gave returned `# tab-insert (not bound)`. Forking the bash shell was interesting (never done that before). I repeated the test after the fork and got a long list of lines in return and in particular noticed this comment: `# TODO: I have removed a "[ -n $tmp ] &&" before 'printf ..',
# and everything works again. If this bug suddenly
# appears again (i.e. "cd /b<TAB>" becomes "cd /"),
# remember to check for other similar conditionals (here
# and _filedir_xspec()). --David`

Comment: I suppose it has something to do with bash completion; my approach would be to check your defined completions using `complete -p` and remove the culprit using `complete -r <culprit>`. The other option is to disable it completely in the running shell using `shopt -u progcomp`. As you mentioned that you are running a Linux distro, which seems to be based on Ubuntu 13.04, I suppose other people will stumble across this type of error and it should be fixed in no time. Another option would be to reinstall bash completion: http://blog.onetechnical.com/2012/06/19/disable-bash-autocompletion-on-ubunt/